# How to show errors inline in codeigniter form validation using ajax form submission?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have made a form that submit on click by JQuery Ajax in Codeigniter framework. If we do codeigniter form validation how could we show the errors message inline next to input fields respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX expects some echo so you have to provide it. Something like:

```
public function check_form_data()
{        
    //here you check your fields

    if $this->form_validation->run() {
        //form passed so echo something to announce AJAX
        echo 'valid';
    } else {
        // array of errors that can be managed in AJAX response part
        echo json_encode($this->form_validation->error_array());
    }
}
```